# Dart: What is the difference when using this keyword and colon after the constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have found some codes that got me confused regarding "this" keyword and the colon after the constructor.

I want to know what the difference between the two is, and what they are for.

**Using colon**

```
class BusinessLogic {
  const BusinessLogic({
    required DataRepository repository,
  }) : _repository = repository;

  final DataRepository _repository;
}
```

**Using `this` keyword**

```
class BusinessLogic {
  const BusinessLogic({
    required this.repository,
  });

  final DataRepository repository;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first sample, `_repository` is a private member, in the second sample, `repository` is a public member.

Apart from that, there's no difference, so if you go with public members everywhere, these 2 samples will be equivalent:

```dart
class BusinessLogic {
  const BusinessLogic({
    required DataRepository repository,
  }) : repository = repository;

  final DataRepository repository;
}

// same as:

class BusinessLogic {
  const BusinessLogic({
    required this.repository,
  });

  final DataRepository repository;
}
```

In Dart, this construction (in the second sample) is called "initializing parameters". You can read more on that [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors).

Comment: Note that if you really did want repository to be private, the first way is the only way to initialize it since `required this._repository` isn't allowed. This is the main motivation for this longer first style.

Comment: wow, that's so quick! I got it. With the colon sample, it wants to make the _repository private.

this._repository can also be used in the constructor parameter, in which case it cannot have an underscore in the first character in the named constructor

Comment: No, it's the underscore that makes parameter private. You cannot have named parameter starting with underscore, that's why you have to use longer version without initializing parameters in that case.